# vector subspaces of $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^3$

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, vector-spaces

How many possible vector subspaces of $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^3$ are there?

My idea was, to proove this as follow:

$$U_b := \left\{\left(\begin{matrix}\lambda_1\\\lambda_2\\\lambda_3\end{matrix}\right) \Bigg|\, a\lambda_1 +b\lambda_2+c\lambda_3+d=0\right\}$$

For $a, b, c, d$ are each $2$ possible combinations, so i've got a maximum of  $2^4=16$  combinations.

Comment: If $d\neq 0$ then this won't give a vector subspace.  This also cannot give one dimensional subspaces.

Comment: $a\lambda_1 +b\lambda_2+c\lambda_3=d$. So are there $2^4+ 2^3+2^2$ possible vector subspaces?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT: Every subspace must have dimension $0,1,2$, or $3$. There is only one subspace of dimension $0$, and of course there is only one subspace of dimension $3$. Each non-zero vector generates a different subspace of dimension $1$; why? That makes the subspaces of dimension $1$ very easy to count.

One very elementary way to count the subspaces of dimension $2$ is to notice that each pair of non-zero vectors generates one of them, but each of them is generated by $3$ different pairs of non-zero vectors (why?).

Comment: Dimension 1: Because there are only 1 and 0, there is only 1 different subspace of dimension 1 (otherwise, i would count the  zero vector twice). Dimension 2: Because $\lambda_1$ could be 1 or 0 $\lambda_2$ also, both can't be zero,  but both could be 1.?

Comment: @fear.xD: No, $\{\langle 0,0,0\rangle,\langle 0,0,1\rangle\}$ and $\{\langle 0,0,0\rangle,\langle 1,0,1\rangle\}$ are already two different one-dimensional subspaces, and they’re not the only ones.

Comment: I would be interested in knowing how you got that each 2-dim space is spanned by 3 pairs. Is it simply that each such subspace has 3 non-trivial elements and any two generate the space, resulting in $\begin{pmatrix} 3 \\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ choices? My technique was to argue that each 2-dim subspace is uniquely specified by a 1-dim complement, hence the number of 2-dim subspaces is equal to the number of 1-dim subspaces.

Comment: @Tyler: Yes: each is simply the Klein $4$-group as an additive group, so any two non-zero vectors generate it, and as you say, there are $\binom32=3$ such pairs. I decided not to use the complement argument, since it requires having established the existence of an inner product on $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^3$.

Comment: @Brain so i can combine 7 vectors (0,0,1),(0,1,0),(0,1,1)(1,1,1),(1,0,0),(1,1,0),(1,0,1)  with the zero vector?

Comment: @fear.xD: You should check that each of those pairings really is a subspace, but yes, each of them is a subspace, and they are all of the one-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: so i have 9 subspaces so far, the zero vector and $(\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z)^3$ + 7 one-dimensional subspaces.  But why exactly is the number of 2-dim subspaces equal to the number of 1-dim subspaces?

Comment: @fear.xD: Because $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^3$ admits the usual inner product, and each two-dim. subspace is the orthogonal complement of a unique one-dim. subspace. But you don’t need this; in my answer I suggested another way of counting the two-dim. subspaces.

Comment: Sorry, but i don't get it. Could you explan your Hint for Dimensin 2 please a bit more?

Comment: @fear.xD: We’ll do this in several steps. Each pair of non-zero vectors generates a two-dim. subspace. How many such pairs are there?

Comment: 6+5+4+3+2+1=21?

Comment: @fear.xD: Yes, or more simply, $\binom72=21$. Okay; that’s potentially $21$ two-dim. subspaces, each containing three non-zero vectors. However, any two of those three non-zero vectors generate the same two-dim. subspace, and there are $3$ pairs of non-zero vectors in each two-dim. subspace. Thus, the count of $21$ actually counts each two-dim. subspace $3$ times, and there are therefore only $\frac{21}3=7$ two-dim. subspaces.

Comment: but why does every of the potentially 21 two-dim. subspaces contains three non-zero vectors? because of $(...)^3$?

Comment: @fear.xD: No. Pick any two of the non-zero vectors and write out all of their linear combinations, until you have the whole subspace that they generate. How many vectors do you get altogether?

Comment: 3, because i can combine every vector using the standard basis?

Comment: @fear.xD: You’re missing an element: no subspace of $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^3$ has exactly $3$ elements. Suppose that you start with $\langle 0,1,1\rangle$ and $\langle 1,0,1\rangle$; what vectors are in their span?

Comment: Which element am i missing?

Comment: @fear.xD: I have no idea, since you didn’t tell me what three elements you actually found. Note that the standard basis has very little to do with the matter.

Comment: $(1,1,0)$ and $(0,0,1)$?

Comment: @fear.xD: If that’s an answer to my question about the span, it’s partly right: the subspace spanned by $\langle 0,1,1\rangle$ and $\langle 1,0,1\rangle$ is $$\{\langle 0,0,0\rangle,\langle 0,1,1\rangle,\langle 1,0,1\rangle,\langle 1,1,0\rangle\}\;.$$ If you check, you’ll find that every linear combination of those four vectors is again one of those four vectors. Every two-dim. subspace or $(\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z)^3$ is similar to that one: it has the form $\{\vec 0,u,v,u+v\}$, where $u$ and $v$ are any two non-zero vectors.

Comment: Ok, i see. And how can i argue for dimension 1, that each non-zero vector generates a different subspace of dimension 1?

Comment: @fear.xD: What is $v+v$ for **every** vector $v$ in that space?

Comment: @Brian i would say it's the zero vector, because $[0]+[0]=[0]$ and also $[1]+[1]=[0]$

Comment: @fear.xD: Yes, and that fact ensures that if $v\ne\vec 0$, then $\{\vec 0,v\}$ is the subspace generated by $v$.